# Alfa AWUS036h has slow speedtest compared to my other wlan card

Tags: wireless-networking, windows-10, internet-speed, speedtest

I am running Win10 (upgraded, not a clean install) and have two wlan cards. One of them, a qualcomm, was included in the packaging of something else when I bought my PC parts... so it is nothing special.
When I bought my PC, I already owned a Alfa AWUS036H and I believe that thing should be superior.

So I used the alfa. But in the last two weeks, without having changed something on purpose (except probably some windows updates), I started lagging no matter if in a game or just googling. Sometimes, longer ago, the other devices in the Wlan did lag too, so I blamed the ISP or the router. But in the last two weeks, I started lagging so hard that I stopped gaming online. My brothers' laptop didn't experience any lags at all.

Today, we played a bot game together to test my lags, and we both lagged until the router decided to do something. First, the Wlan disappeared, then it appeared as open and at last, it was back again as a password protected Wlan.
Until here, you could explain the lags with the fact, that we were simultaneously gaming, thus maybe causing too much traffic. (But what did the router do and why?)
But from here on, I disconnected the alfa and connected with the qualcomm and from then on, we both didn't experience any more lags.

This caused me to run some speedtests on speedtest.net
The following list is chronological

```
CARD       DOWN (Mbps)      UP(Mbps)     PING (ms)
qualcomm   20.92            10.66        10
alfa       6.56             10.44        10
qualcomm   18               10
qualcomm   20               10           10
alfa       12.26            10.7         14
both together  17           10           8
both together  22           10           10
alfa       6.41             10           10
qualcomm   13.98            10.65        12
qualcomm   26.66            9.04         9
```

Apparently, the up speed stays the same but the down speed is way worse with the alfa. Both are worse than the 50Mbps my ISP says we pay for though.

When I `ping -t www.google.com`, the results stay constant between 8 and 20 if I do nothing else, no matter the wlan card.

Some time passed since the last speedtests. I downloaded and installed some windows updates. Now, with a different server but still using speedtest.net, it looks like this.

```
CARD       DOWN (Mbps)      UP(Mbps)     PING (ms)
alfa       3.87             8.9          8
qualcomm  15.55            10.63        10
both      2.67             8.64         10
qualcomm  16.81            10.38        10
alfa      1.97             6.86         10
```

the ping to google is still the same, so this server is probably a bit slower than the last one. But the difference is visible so what.

Now, what I hope somebody here can tell me is:

- Why does the router sometimes stop the wlan, then open it, then close it again?
- Why is the alfa so slow in comparison?

One thing I didn't mention yet, because I cannot reproduce it, is the following: Doing a google search on the PC with alfa seems to interfere with the ping on the laptop (and on the PC as well). Doing the same search on the laptop does neither influence the ping on the PC nor the one on the laptop.

**What I already tried**
I downloaded the latest drivers for my alfa card. They were dated with 2016 but my PC says I already have them installed...

I set Windows update to not use P2P (aka fill my bandwith by updating strangers pcs), it asks me when to download and I even tried the checkbox to ignore updates completely. the last one didn't change anything though.

Disconnecting every other device from the Wifi did sometimes help with earlier issues but right now I even lag with almost no other devices in the Wlan.

I have not yet played a whole match of League of Legends with the qualcomm card yet, but I intend to do so to see if the alfa was actually the (only) problem.

**Edit:**

> first off not knowing what the Qualcomm device is specifically, what
>   router they are connecting too, if they are both connected
>   simultaneously to the same router (which could in itself be the cause
>   of the problem if they are both in use at the same time), how your
>   testing the speeds, etc

I'm sorry for not having said this yet, but thanks for the remark!
The Wlan cards were never at the same time connected to the router except when I wrote "both" in the speedtest results. These results come from speedtest.net using chrome.
When they are in at the same time, they have different ips (if that is important).

The following is the part of `systeminfo`about my installed Network adapters.

```
[01]: Realtek RTL8187 Wireless 802.11b/g 54Mbps USB 2.0 Network Adapter
                                                 Verbindungsname: alfa
                                                 Status:          Medien getrennt
                                           [02]: Qualcomm Atheros AR946x Wireless Network Adapter
                                                 Verbindungsname: qualcomm
                                                 DHCP aktiviert:  Ja
                                                 DHCP-Server:     192.168.100.5
                                                 IP-Adresse(n)
                                                 [01]: 192.168.100.110
                                                 [02]: fe80::256a:6d6e:ba89:6d4d
                                           [03]: TAP-Windows Adapter V9
                                                 Verbindungsname: LAN-Verbindung 4
                                                 Status:          Medien getrennt
                                           [04]: Cisco AnyConnect Secure Mobility Client Virtual Miniport Adapter for Windows x64
                                                 Verbindungsname: LAN-Verbindung 5
                                                 Status:          Hardware nicht vorhanden
                                           [05]: Intel(R) Ethernet Connection I217-V
                                                 Verbindungsname: LAN-Verbindung
                                                 Status:          Medien getrennt
                                           [06]: Bluetooth Device (Personal Area Network)
                                                 Verbindungsname: Bluetooth-Netzwerkverbindung 2
                                                 Status:          Medien getrennt
                                           [07]: LogMeIn Hamachi Virtual Ethernet Adapter
                                                 Verbindungsname: Hamachi
                                                 DHCP aktiviert:  Ja
                                                 DHCP-Server:     25.0.0.1
                                                 IP-Adresse(n)
                                                 [01]: 25.134.101.248
                                                 [02]: fe80::b920:e1bf:e6d0:358f
                                                 [03]: 2620:9b::1986:65f8
```

The ethernet connection is completely unused, as is bluetooth. The CiscoAnyconnect is a VPN which is usually not running, as is the Hamachi. I do not know what the TAP-Windows Adapter V9 is, but its status is "media disconnected" so i guess it doesn't matter.

The router is a D-Link DIR 655 running Firmware Version 2.09 and Hardware Version B1. The complete setup is kinda tricky though, because at the initial setting up of the Wlan (which is quite some time ago), some stuff did not work. I the router connects to a UPC cablecom router which is running in router mode because bridge mode didn't work and using it directly as router made other problems.

I have now tested the qualcomm with a LeagueOfLegends match and am now 90% sure that the lag is exclusive to the alfa

Comment: Your post leaves more questions than answers, first off not knowing what the Qualcomm device is specifically, what router they are connecting too, if they are both connected simultaneously to the same router (which could in itself be the cause of the problem if they are both in use at the same time), how your testing the speeds, etc.

Comment: @acejavelin please see my edit :)